# tikz matrix of nodes in tabularx

Tags: tikz-pgf, tabularx, tikz-matrix

I try to put two tikzpictures containing each a matrix of nodes next to each other in a tabularx spanning the whole textwidth. Here is what I tried

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{XX}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix [matrix of nodes]
{
8 & 1 & 6 \\
3 & 5 & 7 \\
4 & 9 & 2 \\
};
\end{tikzpicture} & \begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix [matrix of nodes]
{
8 & 1 & 6 \\
3 & 5 & 7 \\
4 & 9 & 2 \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

However, with this code I get the following error

! Undefined control sequence.
 \pgf@matrix@last@nextcell@options

l.24 \end{tabularx}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type`I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

What am I doing wrong?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE! There are too many `&` around, meaning that if the compiler sees a `&` it does not now whether this is to separate table or matrix cells. So you need to distinguish between these two options, which can be done by using `ampersand replacement` for the `&` of the matrices.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{XX}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix [matrix of nodes,ampersand replacement=\&]
{
8 \& 1 \& 6 \\
3 \& 5 \& 7 \\
4 \& 9 \& 2 \\
};
\end{tikzpicture} & \begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix [matrix of nodes,ampersand replacement=\&]
{
8 \& 1 \& 6 \\
3 \& 5 \& 7 \\
4 \& 9 \& 2 \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]